# Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - when i use axios in react not with postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

When I make a request using postman to the server, I don't get the "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. But when I integrate with react.js, i keep getting the error. I would for someone to help look for the error. Thanks. Thanks in advance."

Cart.js (client)

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../../components/Header/Header'
import './Cart.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import Loader from '../../components/Loader/Loader';
import {toast} from 'react-toastify'
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'
import CartProduct from '../../components/CartProduct/CartProduct';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import OrderDetails from '../../components/CartPricing/CartPricing';
import Empty from '../../components/Empty/Empty';

toast.configure();
    
function Cart({title, clientRootUrl, apiRootUrl, loggedInStatus, token, errorMessage, cartNum,decreaseCartNum, requireAuth}) {

    document.title = `Cart - ${title}`;

    /** 
     * To 2 d.p.
     * Text: parseFloat("123.456").toFixed(2)
     * Number: num.toFixed(2);
     */

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [cartProducts, setCartProducts] = useState([]);
    const [allowed, setAllowed] = useState(false);
    const [subTotals, setSubTotals] = useState(0);
    const [delivery, setDelivery] = useState(0); // use request to get details
    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
    const [all,setAll] = useState(false);

    
    /** Pass the ffg data to App.js
     * cart
     * subtotal
     * delivery
     * total
     */

    useEffect(() => {
        // setIsLoading(true);
        axios.post(`${apiRootUrl}miscellaneous/fee`, 
        {
            subtotal: subTotals
        },
        {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
        })
        .then(({data})=>{
            // setIsLoading(false);
            setDelivery(data.cost);
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            // setIsLoading(false);
            console.log(err)
            // toast.error(errorMessage, {
            //     position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT
            // })
        })

    }, [total])

    useEffect(() => {
        setTotal(subTotals + delivery);
    }, [delivery])

    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get(`${apiRootUrl}cart/`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
        .then(({data})=>{
            let cartItems = data;
            // setCartProducts(data);
            // console.log(cartItems)

            if(cartItems.length < 1) {
                setIsLoading(false);
            } else {
                cartItems.map(({id,productId,quantity})=>{
                    // cart: id, productId // product details
                    axios.get(`${apiRootUrl}product/${productId}`)
                    .then(({data})=>{
                        setIsLoading(false);
                        setAllowed(true); // show details            
                        let product = data;
                        // no storing the previous one being asynchronous, so we have to use the previous in the argument
                        setCartProducts(prevCartProducts => [ ... prevCartProducts, {
                            cartId:id,
                            quantity:quantity,
                            id:product.id,
                            categoryId: product.categoryId,
                            name: product.name,
                            description: product.description,
                            image: product.image,
                            price: product.price
                        }]);

                    })
                    .catch(err=>{
                        setIsLoading(false);
                        console.log(err)
                        // toast.error(errorMessage, {
                        //     position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT
                        // })
                    })
                })
            }
        })

        .catch(err=>{
            setIsLoading(false);
            // toast.error(errorMessage, {
            //     position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT
            // })      
            console.log(err)
        })
    },[apiRootUrl])


    function delCartItem(cartId) {
        


        // delete from DB
        setIsLoading(true);
        axios.delete(`${apiRootUrl}cart/${cartId}`,{
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
        .then(({data})=>{
            setIsLoading(false);
            if(data.error === 0) {
                toast.success(data.message, {
                    position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT
                })
                setCartProducts([...cartProducts.filter(cartProduct=>cartProduct.cartId !== cartId)]);

                // reduce cartNum by 1
                decreaseCartNum();
            } else {
                toast.error(errorMessage, {
                    position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT
                })
            }
            if(cartProducts.length-1 < 1) {
                setAllowed(false);
            } else {
                // as products are being deleted , RECALCULATE VALUES

                // total prices will change authomatically
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            setIsLoading(false);
            // toast.error(errorMessage, {
            //     position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT
            // })
            console.log(err)

        })
    }

    function addSubTotals(subTotal) {
        // setSubTotals(prevSubTotals=>prevSubTotals+subTotal);
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        /** Get The Delivery Cost of The Products @ The Good Time */

        setTotal(subTotals+delivery);


    }, [subTotals])

    useEffect(() => {
        let sum = 0;
        cartProducts.map((p)=>{
            let subtotal = Number(p.price) * Number(p.quantity);
            sum+=subtotal;
        })
        setSubTotals(sum);   

        

    }, [cartProducts])

    function calculateNewSubTotalAndTotal(newQuantity, cartId) {

        // update quantity and update of the specific cartId
        const elementsIndex = cartProducts.findIndex(item=>item.cartId === cartId)  
        let newCartProducts = [...cartProducts];
        newCartProducts[elementsIndex] = {...newCartProducts[elementsIndex], quantity:newQuantity}
        setCartProducts(newCartProducts);
    }

    // function payWithPaystack(e) {
    //     e.preventDefault();
    //     let handler = PaystackPop.setup({
    //       key: 'sk_test_f12711e9277e1a27aba8e58f3394b9717098efaf', // Replace with your public key
    //       email: "______",
    //       amount: 1200 * 100,
    //       ref: ''+Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1), // generates a pseudo-unique reference. Please replace with a reference you generated. Or remove the line entirely so our API will generate one for you
    //       // label: "Optional string that replaces customer email"
    //       onClose: function(){
    //         alert('Window closed.');
    //       },
    //       callback: function(response){
    //         let message = 'Payment complete! Reference: ' + response.reference;
    //         alert(message);
    //       }
    //     });
    //     handler.openIframe();
    //   }


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
             {requireAuth()}
            {isLoading && <Loader />}
           
            <Header title = {title} clientRootUrl = {clientRootUrl} loggedInStatus = {loggedInStatus} cartNum = {cartNum} token = {token} />

            <br />
            <br />
            
            <div className = "small-container cart-page">

                {
                    (cartProducts.length > 0) && (
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Subtotal</th>
                            </tr>

                            {
                                cartProducts.map(({cartId,quantity,id,categoryId,name,description,image,price,out_of_stock})=><CartProduct key = {id} cartId = {cartId} quantity = {quantity} id = {id} categoryId = {categoryId} name = {name} description = {description} image = {image} price = {price} out_of_stock = {out_of_stock} apiRootUrl = {apiRootUrl} token = {token} errorMessage = {errorMessage} delCartItem = {delCartItem} addSubTotals = {addSubTotals} calculateNewSubTotalAndTotal = {calculateNewSubTotalAndTotal} />)
                            }
                        </table>
                    )
                }

                {
                    (cartProducts.length < 1) && (
                        <Fragment>
                            <Empty clientRootUrl = {clientRootUrl}>Ahh! Your cart seems empty.</Empty>
                        </Fragment>
                    )
                }
        
                { (allowed) && (
                    <OrderDetails subTotals = {subTotals} delivery = {delivery} total = {total} >
                        <Link to = {`/checkout`} className = "btn">Proceed to Checkout</Link>
                    </OrderDetails>
                )}
                
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Cart
```

app.js (server)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const userRoutes = require('./api/routes/user');
const adminRoutes = require('./api/routes/admin');
const categoryRoutes = require('./api/routes/category');
const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/product');
const orderRoutes = require('./api/routes/order');
const marketRoutes = require('./api/routes/market');
const searchRoutes = require('./api/routes/search');
const cartRoutes = require('./api/routes/cart');
const miscellaneousRoutes = require('./api/routes/miscellaneous');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req,res,next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"); // change later
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );
    // res.header("Cache-Control", 'no-cache');
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
        res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});

app.use('/user', userRoutes);
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use('/category', categoryRoutes);
app.use('/product', productRoutes);
app.use('/order', orderRoutes);
app.use('/market', marketRoutes);
app.use('/search', searchRoutes);
app.use('/cart', cartRoutes);
app.use('/miscellaneous', miscellaneousRoutes);


// sample code to create static filepath
// app.use('/uploads', express.static('img'));

app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

app.use((req,res,next) => {
     const error = new Error('Not found');
     error.status = 404;
     next(error);
 });

 app.use((error,req,res,next) => {
     res.status(error.status || 500);
     res.json({
         error: {
             message:error.message 
         }
     });
 });

module.exports = app;
```

cart.js (server(controller))

```
const pool = require('../../utils/pool');

exports.cart_get_all_for_user = (req,res,next) => {
    const tokenUserId = req.userData.userId;
    // const tokenEmail = req.userData.email;

    // if(userId == tokenUserId || tokenEmail === process.env.adminEmail) {
        pool.getConnection(function(err,conn){
            if(err) {
                return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'});
            } else {
                conn.query(`select * from cartSchema where userId = ?`, [tokenUserId], function(err,result){
                    conn.release();
                    if(err) {
                        return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'});
                    } else {
                        return res.status(200).json(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // res.end();
    // } else {
    //     res.status(401).json({error:'No authorization!'});
    // }
}

exports.add_to_cart = (req,res,next) => {
    const { productId, quantity } = req.body;
    const { userId } = req.userData;

    pool.getConnection(function(err,conn){
        if(err) {
            return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'});
        } else {
            pool.getConnection(function(err,conn){
                if(err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'});
                } else {
                    conn.query(`select * from cartSchema where ( productId = ?) and ( userId = ? )`, [ productId,userId], function(err,cart_product){
                        // conn.release();
                        if(err) {
                            return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'});
                        } else {
                            if(cart_product.length > 0) {

                                // update quantity in cart
                                conn.query(`update cartSchema set quantity = ? where ( productId = ?) and ( userId = ? )`, [quantity,productId,userId], function(err,result){
                                    if(err) {
                                        return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'});
                                    } else {
                                        return res.status(200).json({error:455,message:'Product already exists in cart but the quantity has been updated'});
                                    } 
                                });

                            } else {
                                conn.query(`insert into cartSchema (userId, productId, quantity) values (?,?,?)`, [userId,productId, quantity], function(err,result){
                                    conn.release();
                                    if(err) {
                                        return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'});
                                    } else {
                                        return res.status(200).json({
                                            error: 0,
                                            message: 'Product has been added to cart',
                                            id: result.insertId,
                                            userId,
                                            productId,
                                            quantity
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    }); 
}

// update quantity
exports.update_cart_product_details = (req,res,next) => {
    const {cartId} = req.params;
    const {quantity} = req.body;
    const {userId} = req.userData;

    /** 
     * check if cartItem exists <i>
     * check if the user is authorized to change <i>
     * update cartItem
     * give success message
     */
    pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occured. Please try again!' });
            } else {
                conn.query(`select * from cartSchema where id = ? and userId = ?`, [cartId,userId], (err,cartItem) => {
                    if(err) {
                        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occured. Please try again!' });
                    } else {
                        console.log(cartItem)
                        if(cartItem.length < 1) {
                            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occured. Please try again!' }); // The CartItem you're trying to update does not exist
                        } else {
                            conn.query(`update cartSchema set quantity = ? where ( id = ? and userId = ? )`, [quantity,cartId,userId], (err,result)=>{
                                conn.release();
                                if(err) {
                                    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occured. Please try again!' });
                                } else {
                                    return res.status(200).json({error:0,message:"Quantity updated successfully"});
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        })
}

exports.remove_from_cart = (req,res,next) => {
    const { cartId } = req.params;
    const {userId} = req.userData;

    pool.getConnection(function(err,conn){
        if(err) {
            return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'});
        } else {

            conn.query(`select * from cartSchema where id = ? and userId = ?`, [cartId,userId], (err,cartItem)=>{
                if(err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occured. Please try again!' });
                } else {
                    if(cartItem.length < 1) {
                        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occured. Please try again!' }); // The CartItem you're trying to update does not exist
                    } else {
                        conn.query(`delete from cartSchema where id = ?`, [cartId], function(err,result){   
                            conn.release();
                            if(err) {
                                return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'});
                            } else {
                                return res.status(200).json({error:0,message:'Product successfully removed from cart'});
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            })

            
        }
    });
}
```

miscellaneous.js

```
exports.city_cost = (req,res,next) => {
    const {city} = req.params;
    console.log(city)
    return res.status(200).json({
        fee:checkLocationFee(city)
    })    
}

exports.delivery_cost = (req,res,next) => {
    
    const {userId} = req.userData;

    /** Get the city of the user */
    pool.getConnection((err,conn)=>{
        if(err) {
            logisticFees = logisticDefaultFee;
        } else {
            conn.query(`select * from userSchema where id = ?`, [userId], (err,user)=>{
                if(err) {
                    logisticFees = logisticDefaultFee;
                } else {
                    logisticFees = checkLocationFee(user[0].city); 
                }
            });
        }
    });

    console.log(logisticFees)

    // const logisticFees = 1000; /** logistic fees varies based on LOCATION */

    const { subtotal } = req.body;

    /** FoodNet Logic */
    let FoodNetFees;

    if(subtotal < 1000) {   
        FoodNetFees = ((2.5/100)*subtotal) + 100;  // 1.5 (down)
    } else if(subtotal <= 5000) {
        FoodNetFees = ((3/100)*subtotal) + 100; 
    } else if(subtotal > 5000 && subtotal <= 50000){
        FoodNetFees = ((3.5/100)*subtotal) + 100;
    } else { // above 50000
        FoodNetFees = ((4/100)*subtotal) + 100;
    }
    /** ../end */

    const paystackPaymentFee = ( subtotal + FoodNetFees + logisticFees ) * (1.5/100);

    const paystackTransferFee = 10; // off transfer made to them

    const totalCost = FoodNetFees + logisticFees + paystackPaymentFee + paystackTransferFee; // err to add subtotal

    return res.status(200).json({
        cost: totalCost
    })
}

exports.verify_transaction = (req,res,next) => {

    const {userId} = req.userData;

    pool.getConnection((err,conn)=>{
        if(err) {
            logisticFees = logisticDefaultFee;
        } else {
            conn.query(`select * from userSchema where id = ?`, [userId], (err,user)=>{
                if(err) {
                    logisticFees = logisticDefaultFee;
                } else {
                    logisticFees = checkLocationFee(user[0].city); 
                }
            });
        }
    });

    const { reference } = req.params;

    /** Verify Transaction (1) */
    const promise = paystack.verifyTransaction({
        reference
    })

    promise.then(function ({body}){
        if(body.data.status === 'success') {
            /** Create Transfer Recepient (2) */
            const promise2 = paystack.createTransferRecipient({
                type:"nuban",
                name: logisticName,
                account_number:logisticAccNumber,
                bank_code:logisticBankCode,
                currency:"NGN"
            })
            promise2.then(function({body}){
                if(body.data.active === true) {
                    /** Make Transfer with Recipient(3) */
                    // store recipient_code
                    const recipient_code = body.data.recipient_code;
                    console.log(recipient_code)
                    
                    /** JUST FOR DEVELOPMENT MODE ( REMOVE IN PRODUCTION MODE ) */
                    return res.status(200).json({error:0});

                    /** FOR PRODUCTION MODE BELOW */
                    // initiate transfer
                    const promise3 = paystack.initiateTransfer({
                        source:"balance",
                        reason: logisticReason,
                        amount: 900 * 100,
                        recipient: recipient_code,
                        reference: Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1)
                    })
                    promise3.then(function({body}){
                        if(body.data.status === "success") {
                            // will only work with real transactions
                            res.status(200).json({error:0})
                        } else {
                            /** Handle Error */
                            return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'})
                        }
                    }).catch(function(err){
                        /** Handle Error */
                        return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'})
                    });
                    /** FOR PRODUCTION MODE ABOVE */

                } else {
                    /** Handle Error */
                    return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'})
                }
            })
        } else {
            /** Handle Error */
            // console.log(2)  
            return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'})
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
        /** Handle Error */
        return res.status(500).json({error:'An error occured. Please try again!'})
    })
    // put return in all response
}
```

Comment: the way you've nested the promises in `miscellaneous` is not good, though, probably not your problem - the fact that you only have an issue when dealing with CORS, suggests that the issue is with the handling of the `OPTIONS` request method - check what your code does for an OPTIONS request

Comment: I think the solution may be `return res.status(200).json({});` in the handling of OPTIONS, since you don't want to continue processing the request at this stage

Comment: Thanks a lot. "Cannot set headers..." has gone away. But the react cart page keeps pausing when i try to reload the page twice. It seems to get stuck. It is because there are so many requests. Please can we connect via whatsapp or something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The client seems to really depend on the OPTIONS request

Comment: thats a CORS preflight

Comment: I keep getting this after reloading twice or thrice `GET /cart/ - - ms - -`

Comment: The server stops handling request without giving any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got solved. I was making multiple requests to the server being asynchronous code. So i just nested my requests to the stay in the safe space and all worked perfectly.

Comment: please mark your (own) answer as accepted